# Терминал VScode не видит Node.js (node: команда не найдена)

Tags: javascript, linux, node.js, консоль, visual-studio-code

Установил Node.js - скачал архив для Linux с официального сайта. Распаковал по инструкции и добавил путь в PATH - прописал в profile:

```
# Nodejs
VERSION=v14.16.0
DISTRO=linux-x64
export PATH=/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-$VERSION-$DISTRO/bin:$PATH
```

Выполнил обновление profile:

```
 ~$ . ~/.profile
```

Перезагрузил компьютер.

При запуске с основного терминала Linux все работает:

```
~$ node -v
v14.16.0

~$ npm version
{
  npm: '6.14.11',
  ares: '1.16.1',
  brotli: '1.0.9',
  cldr: '37.0',
  icu: '67.1',
  llhttp: '2.1.3',
  modules: '83',
  napi: '7',
  nghttp2: '1.41.0',
  node: '14.16.0',
  openssl: '1.1.1j',
  tz: '2020a',
  unicode: '13.0',
  uv: '1.40.0',
  v8: '8.4.371.19-node.18',
  zlib: '1.2.11'
}

~$ npx -v
6.14.11
```

Те же команды в терминале VScode дают такой результат:

```
sh-5.1$ node -v
sh: node: команда не найдена
```

System:  Kernel: 5.4.0-66-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.8.6
wm: muffin dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal

Comment: Чем вам не устраивала команда `apt install nodejs`?

`

Comment: возможно, у автора вопроса древненький линукс и там очень древняя версия в репах.

Comment: Тот же эффект. Пробовал сначала через apt install nodejs

System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-66-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.8.6 
wm: muffin dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 20.1 Ulyssa base: Ubuntu 20.04 focal

Comment: я кажется знаю причину. У Вас разные эмуляторы терминалов. Попробуйте выполнить `echo $SHELL` в каждом с терминалов. Скорее всего в "обычном" получите `/usr/bin/bash`, а в редакторе - `/usr/bin/sh`. Если так, тогда понятно что делать.

Comment: Да Вы правы! В терминал linux /bin/bash, а в VScode /bin/sh Я еще только новичок в этих вопросах и буду признателен за разъяснение))

Answer (score 1):

Вся проблема в том, что используются разные программы эмуляторы терминалов. А они используют разные файлы для настроек. И то, что один терминал "видит", второй - нет.

Определить текущий используемый терминал обычно можно так

echo $SHELL

или любой другой командой в данном терминале (например, можно распечатать через env).

Думаю, самый простой способ - это все таки в vscode использовать тот же терминал, что и в "основной части". Так просто будет легче.

[Переключается где то так](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1117868/change-default-terminal-back-to-bash-in-vs-code)

- В VSCode зайти в меню File>Preferences>Settings. или нажать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>;
- Начните печатать terminal.integrated.shell.linux поле поиска;
- Найдите ключ Terminal > Integrated > Shell:Linux и впишите туда /bin/bash (или возможно /usr/bin/bash). Перезапустите редактор

Должно заработать.

И да, если только нет очень веских причин, устанавливайте софт с официальных репозиториев.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но почему-то терминал не переключается (даже после перезагрузки компьютера) Причем в VScode появилась надпись bash. Но при вводе:
:~$ node -v
bash: node: команда не найдена
:~$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh

Попробую покапать в этом направлении

Comment: попробуйте тогда по простому. просто в консоли редактора напишите /bin/bash и пробуйте

Comment: Вроде и переключается, но по факту нет. Может потому что у меня установлен gnome-terminal (вместе с системой шел такой)

`sh-5.1$ /bin/bash
kadenza@kadenza44:~/VScodeProjects/test3$ node -v
bash: node: команда не найдена
kadenza@kadenza44:~/VScodeProjects/test3$ echo $SHELL
/bin/sh`

Comment: Кстати если в основном терминале набрать  `/bin/sh` то он переключается и все команды из него работают как надо

Comment: правильно, потому что он наследует настройки. А попробуйте запустить ноду по полному пути, то есть, где то так `/usr/bin/node`. Если и так не запуститься, тогда остается странное - это терминалы от разных машин (я понимаю, но все может быть)

Comment: я так понял что проблема в правах доступа. Терминал VScode даже не видит папки где находится `node`. И так же при команде echo `$Path` он не отображает путь до `node`. В основном терминале линукса при той же команде путь отображается

Comment: Тут похоже не в правах дело. Такое ощущение, что оно как будто в докере отдельном запускается